# Definition of a Vertex

Tags: definition, plane-geometry

While working with a student today, I had the unfortunate realization that I do not actually know a *rigourous* definition for a vertex (here in the sense of plane geometry). It didn't stop us from working, thankfully, but it has been nagging at me since.

What is a vertex of a polygon?

I think a definition that satisfies me would be:

1. "Clearly" able to be phrased in ZFC, and not an alternate axiomatic system for the purposes of plane geometry (sorry Hilbert)
2. Able to be "worked with", though not necessarily be easy or intuitive to work with.
3. Capture various "intuitive" notions of vertices (that they are pieces of a polygon, that they are formed by straight edges, that a hexagon has six), while avoiding including "unnatural" vertices (in particular, I would not like to consider an intersection of two curves to be a vertex).

One option I considered was "the image of the convex hull of the $n$th roots of unity under a homeomorphism which preserves the linearity of the edges" is a polygon, and then the images of the roots of unity are the vertices, but I am not overly satisfied by this. What are some alternate definitions?

Comment: If one can provide an explicit translation from some "alternate axiomatic system" down in to ZFC, does that count enough? If not, do you actually mean something like "What's a definition of polygon that's very close to 'a certain kind of subset of $\mathbb R^2$' and then what would the corresponding definition of vertex be?"

Comment: Are you only ever going to be working with a single polygon or will you work with other arrangements such as tilings? Are you allowed the notion of line segments? Could you define a vertex as the intersection of 2 or more line segments?  Would allowing a vertex to be the intersection of infinitely many line segments be ok or not? Sorry for all the questions, you have already disqualified some of the standard definitions that I have read.

Comment: @Mark S. "What's a definition of polygon that's very close to 'a certain kind of subset of R2' and then what would the corresponding definition of vertex be?" - Yes, exactly.

Comment: @openproblem I'm not particularly interested in tilings. Let's say a single polygon for the moment. Line segments are OK, as you can view them as degenerate 2gons and 1gons, depending on the definitions, but I would not like to include, say, a bent line-segment as a polygon. I am curious as to your standard definitions though.